# How does Http.sys URL Prefix Registration translate into IIS bindings config?

Tags: url, iis-7, binding, web-config, prefix

Windows HTTP Server API provides mechanisms for URL Registration and Reservation so that request queues can be setup by processes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364483(v=VS.85).aspx.

And the URL matching is done by longest matching URL Prefix. With support for strong wild cards '+' and weak wild cards '*'.

I get that IIS does some mangling/translation of binding in web.config to HTTP Server API (http.sys) for URL registration. (URL Group and HTTP Request Queue).

Could someone throw some light here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `netsh http show servicestate` on a machine with IIS installed and some web sites configured should give you a good representation of how IIS sets up the URL groups and ties them to request queues.